# obtener todos los documentos donde tipo sea igual a seguidor

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

//aqui el modelo de usuario

```
const notiSchema = new Schema({
  _id: {type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true},
  de:[]
}, {
   timestamps: true
});
```

//tengo la siguiente consulta para mongodb

```
notis.findById(req.userId)
  .populate({path: 'usuarios'})
  .exec((error, result: any)=>{
      console.log(result);
})
```

esto es lo que me devuelve `result` por consola[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

//estoy haciendo un sistema de notificaciones, cada usuario tiene un documento aparte llamado `notis`, en el tiene un apartado llamado `de` donde es un array con objetos, cada objeto tiene el id del usuario que genero la notificacion, el tipo de notificacion y el estado que es como el visto, lo que trato de generar en mi consulta es obtener todos los documentos donde `tipo` sea igual a `seguidor`, me explico?

Comment: Si no tienes una referencia explícita usando `ref` en tu documento, la forma de hacerlo es con agregación, no con `populate()`. O realizar una segunda consulta con los documentos devueltos. Creo que te prepararé una respuesta. Saludos

Comment: gracias, esperare esa respuesta

Comment: Me enreda un poco que tu esquema se llama `userSchema` pero tu consulta la hagas sobre un modelo llamado `notis`. ¿podrías aclarar un poco ese punto? Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Puedes resolver el problema usando una consulta compuesta o un método de agregación.

Como norma general, siempre es preferible usar una consulta con filtros antes que una agregación, esto más que nada por la sobrecarga en el motor de BD que significa realizar un proceso de agregación.

Sin embargo, hay situaciones en las que un proceso de agregación puede ser la única forma de filtrar los datos que requerimos.

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea consultar la colección de usuarios, de tal forma que los documentos devueltos se correspondan con el tipo `seguidor`. Basados en los datos almacenados en el campo `de` (de la colección `notis`), el cual es una lista de documentos con la siguiente estructura:

```js
{
  _id:    <Tipo ObjectId (coincidente con un campo _id de la colección de usuarios)>,
  estado: <Tipo Number (entero)>,
  tipo:   <Tipo String (ejemplo: 'seguidor')>
}
```

Se desea devolver todos los usuarios de tipo `seguidor` que aparecen en la lista `de` del documento `notis` consultado por `_id`.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Viendo la estructura de tu documento `notis`, podemos hacer la siguiente consulta:

```
Notis.findById(id, '-_id de', (error, result) => {
  if(error) {
    // lógica para el error
  }
  console.log(result);
  // ...
});
```

Con esto no hemos hecho nada muy diferente de como lo tenías, pero en mi consulta, explícitamente indico que no deseo el campo `_id`, además pido explícitamente el campo `de`, y el resto de campos que pueda tener mi colección no los quiero, por tanto no los escribo en la proyección.

El resultado de dicha consulta puede ser algo parecido al siguiente:

```js
{
  de: [
    { _id: '5e9af75782b4212fc42c4b0c', estado: '0', tipo: 'seguidor' },
    { _id: '5e9af77182b4212fc42c4b0e', estado: '0', tipo: 'seguidor' },
    { _id: '5e9af8c882b4212fc42c4b16', estado: '0', tipo: 'no seguidor' }
  ]
}
```

Esto muestra 2 documentos de tipo *seguidor* y 1 documento de tipo *no seguidor*. Lo siguiente que debemos hacer es filtrar el resultado, para obtener
los documentos que sean sólo de tipo *seguidor*. Para ello nos apoyaremos en el método [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) del tipo `Array`.

```
const seguidores = result.de.filter(element => element.tipo === 'seguidor');
```

Con esto obtenemos una lista de los usuarios de tipo *seguidor*:

```
[
  { _id: '5e9af75782b4212fc42c4b0c', estado: '0', tipo: 'seguidor' },
  { _id: '5e9af77182b4212fc42c4b0e', estado: '0', tipo: 'seguidor' },
]
```

Ahora podemos consultar la colección de usuarios usando el `_id` de cada documento de la lista.

Como las consultas a la base de datos son asíncronas, debemos usar algún método para realizar todas las consultas independientemente del tamaño de la lista devuelta.

Una forma de hacerlo es usando [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise/all), el cual nos devolverá una promesa cuyo estado será `fullfilled` sólo si cada respuesta asíncrona de la consulta hecha sobre cada elemento de la lista sea satisfactoria.

Una forma de hacerlo es:

```js
Promise.all(seguidores.map(seguidor => {
  return User.findById(seguidor._id, 'nombre apellidos', (error, user) => {
    if(error) {
      error.onElement = `Error al consultar _id: ${seguidor._id}`;
      throw error;
    }
    return user;
  });
}))
.then(users => {
  console.log(users);
  // ...
  // código para enviar o trabajar con el resultado
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log(error.onElement);
  console.error(error.message);
  // ...
  // lógica para manejar el error
});
```

Analicemos el código:

1. Sobre el Array de seguidores usamos el método [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map) que nos devolverá una lista con los usuarios traidos de la base de datos.
2. Este array lo pasamos directamente como argumento al método `all()` del objeto `Promise`.
3. Como `Promise` es un objeto que implementa o devuelve una promesa, usamos los métodos `then()` y `catch()` de las promesas.
4. Lo que devuelve cada elemento al método `map()` es el usuario cuyo `_id` concuerda con el filtro de la consulta.
5. Si hubiera un error en alguno de los elementos al consultar sobre la BD, se lanza el error y el mismo es capturado por la método `catch()` de la promesa.

Con esto, el resultado de tu consulta puede verse así:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": "5e9af75782b4212fc42c4b0c",
    "nombre": "Arya",
    "apellidos": "Stark"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5e9af77182b4212fc42c4b0e",
    "nombre": "Eddard",
    "apellidos": "Stark"
  }
]
```

Esta es una forma en la que puedes consultar la coleción de usuarios filtrando por *seguidores* o *no seguidores*, según sea el caso.